# Clang-Format: Breaking line in the initializers between members rather than within a member?

Tags: clang-format

I'm trying to format a C++ code with clang-format.

```
// input.hpp

namespace Foo{
    class Bar{
        Bar(bool is_zzz, int nn) : foobar(nullptr), xx{nullptr, nullptr}, yy{0, 0}, zzz(is_zzz), value(xxx_yyy_zzz) {}
    };
}
```

```
// .clang-format

BasedOnStyle: LLVM
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
ColumnLimit: 64

AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: AlwaysBreak
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: All
ContinuationIndentWidth: 8
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Always
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: All
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: true
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BreakBeforeBraces: Attach
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: true
BreakConstructorInitializers: BeforeColon
BreakInheritanceList: BeforeColon
BreakStringLiterals: false
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
FixNamespaceComments: true
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentWrappedFunctionNames: false
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
NamespaceIndentation: All
PointerAlignment: Middle
SortIncludes: false
SortUsingDeclarations: false
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: Never
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
```

clang-format version 9.0.0 produces

```
// output.hpp

namespace Foo {
    class Bar {
        Bar(bool is_zzz, int nn)
            : foobar(nullptr), xx{ nullptr, nullptr }, yy{ 0,
                                                           0 },
              zzz(is_zzz), value(xxx_yyy_zzz) {}
    };
} // namespace Foo
```

This breaks a line within the initializer for `yy` (`{0, 0}`). However, I prefer the following:

```
// output2.hpp

namespace Foo {
    class Bar {
        Bar(bool is_zzz, int nn)
            : foobar(nullptr), xx{ nullptr, nullptr },
              yy{ 0, 0 }, zzz(is_zzz), value(xxx_yyy_zzz) {}
    };
} // namespace Foo
```

that is, prefer breaking a line in the initializers between members rather than within a member. How should I set up `.clang-format`?

Comment: I forgot a note: I would like to know a solution other than changing "ColumnLimit". (In this example I made up "ColumnLimit" value so that this situation occurs.)

Comment: You might like `ConstructorInitializerAllOnOneLineOrOnePerLine: true`. This isn't the format you asked for, but it's better than what you're currently getting.